# MVC IoC Construtor sem parametros

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

Ola.
Minha aplicação esta disparando um erro ao tentar criar um novo item.
Estou recebendo esta mensagem de erro: Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto.

Mas minha classe controller possui esse construtor sem parametros:

```
public AlocacaoController()
{

}

public AlocacaoController(IAlocacaoService alocacaoService, IProfissionalService profissionalService, IContratoService contratoService)
{
            _alocacaoService = alocacaoService;
            _profissionalService = profissionalService;
            _contratoService = contratoService;
            _alocacaoMapper = new AutoMapperAlocacao();
            _contratoMapper = new AutoMapperAlocacaoContrato();
}
```

Esse erro ocorre antes de acionar este metodo.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(AlocacaoViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        //Carregar lista de clientes
        model.ListaContratos = new SelectList(_contratoService.ListarAtivos(), "ContratoID", "Nome", model.ContratoID);
        model.ListaProfissionais = new SelectList(_profissionalService.ListarAtivos(), "ProfissionalID", "Nome", null);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        return View(model);
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Todas as interfaces estão configuradas na minha clase para injeção de dependência:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IBaseService<>)).To(typeof(BaseService<>));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IAlocacaoService)).To(typeof(AlocacaoService));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IClienteService)).To(typeof(ClienteService));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IClienteIpService)).To(typeof(ClienteIpService));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IClienteLocalService)).To(typeof(ClienteLocalService));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IContratoService)).To(typeof(ContratoService));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(ILancamentoService)).To(typeof(LancamentoService));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IProfissionalDispositivoService)).To(typeof(ProfissionalDispositivoService));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IProfissionalService)).To(typeof(ProfissionalService));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IUsuarioService)).To(typeof(UsuarioService));

            kernel.Bind(typeof(IBaseRepository<>)).To(typeof(BaseRepository<>));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IAlocacaoRepository)).To(typeof(AlocacaoRepository));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IClienteRepository)).To(typeof(ClienteRepository));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IClienteIpRepository)).To(typeof(ClienteIpRepository));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IClienteLocalRepository)).To(typeof(ClienteLocalRepository));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IContratoRepository)).To(typeof(ContratoRepository));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(ILancamentoRepository)).To(typeof(LancamentoRepository));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IProfissionalDispositivoRepository)).To(typeof(ProfissionalDispositivoRepository));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IProfissionalRepository)).To(typeof(ProfissionalRepository));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IUsuarioRepository)).To(typeof(UsuarioRepository));
        }
```

Stack Trace:

> [MissingMethodException: Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido
>   para este objeto.] System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +206 System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83 System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
>   +197
>
> [MissingMethodException: Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido
>   para este objeto. Object type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
>   +233 System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindSimpleModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
>   ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult) +285
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +299
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
>   PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder)
>   +17 System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
>   PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) +382
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +122
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model)
>   +55 System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +1230
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +348
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +338
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +105
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__19(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +743
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +14
>
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object
>   state) +328 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1c(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +25
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +30
>
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state) +556 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__14(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +18
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +20
>
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +420
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext
>   requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object
>   asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +30
>
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +369
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +103 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Debugando minha aplicação eu verifiquei que o erro ocorre nesta propriedade get da minha classe model: public virtual SelectList ListaProfissionais { get; set; }. Esta propriedade é utilizada para exibir um dropdown na minha view. Funciona quando esta carregando a view CREATE. Mas da erro ao clicar no botão salvar.

Comment: Você está usando o Castle Windsor?

Comment: Não. Estou utilizando ninject. Mas não me parece que o erro esta na configuração das dependencias, e sim na codificação do meu controle ListBox. Pois o erro esta ocorrendo justamente nessa propriedade ListaProfissionais que e do tipo SelectList, do proprio framework.

Answer (score 1):

Descobri o problema.
O funcionamento do ListBox e um pouco diferente.
Quando você utiliza o metodo ListBoxFor, e necessario passar duas listas.
Uma que armazena os itens que serão apresentados na lista e outra lista que armazena os valores dos itens selecionados.

```
//Itens da lista
public SelectList ListaProfissionais { get; set; }
//Selecao de valores
public IEnumerable<string> Profissionais { get; set; }


@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Profissionais, Model.ListaProfissionais, new { style = "width:250px" })
```

Eu estava passando a mesma lista nos dois metodos.
Por isso o erro ocorria. Só que pela descrição do erro apresentado fica meio difícil adivinhar o que é. Tive que apanhar um pouco para descobrir.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente sua classe **AlocacaoViewModel** possui um construtor, mas está sem um construtor padrão.

Adicione a ela um construtor padrão, depois teste novamente:

```
public AlocacaoViewModel()
{

}
```

Comment: Não funcionou. O problema esta na propriedade que alimenta a listbox: public SelectList ProfissionaisSelecionados { get; set; }

Comment: Ah, tem como você colocar o código do método ListarAtivos utilizado para criar a instância?